# How to deal with Jahzracht?

Tags: valdis-story-abyssal-city

I'm having trouble with Jahzracht, both on the spelling and killing side of things. He does not seem to have a whole lot of vulnerabilities and so far the only thing I've seen that kind of works is trying to deny any damage on his attacks with Aegis (it also cures being on fire). While it does deny any and all damage when active, that's not very reliable, however, and doesn't deal much in terms of damage.

I thought I could kick him out of guard, then push him on the many fire cannons around, but they don't seem to deal any damage to him. Maybe use ice attacks instead? So far I've only got Frozen Shard, replacing Aegis, and Frost Blade, replacing Refresh; I'm not comfortable swapping either of these, so all I'm left with is Arctic Javelin in the air slot (which does mediocre damage) and Ice Tower, which deals no damage at all.

What's the key to this boss?

Comment: Watch his attack pattern, and figure out when he pauses.  When he does, get in close and whale on him a bit, and then get away before he can hit you.  Also try standing on your Ice Tower to avoid his ground-based fire attack.  Lastly, I think you can stand on the cannons on the side to largely avoid being attacked, giving you time to heal.

Answer (score 2):

He's actually fairly easy when you use Frost Blade.  Without it, every 2-3 attacks on the boss will make him use his counter attack, which is the fire circle that surrounds him.  But with Frost Blade, this doesn't trigger, so you can attack him at will.

When he starts blocking your attacks, use a heavy attack to break his guard.  He will then jump on the side of the room and then jump back in the middle to unleash his fire attack.  You can jump approximately where he lands to avoid said fire attack, and then just spam your regular attacks again.

He will use the Fire Vortex 3 times or so during the fight (at fixed life values).  To avoid it, go in one of the corners, and try to avoid the little lasers that will pop up.  They pop right above your head, so move a little to dodge them all.  You should have enough space in a corner to never get hit by those.

Rince and repeat and he'll be gone in no time.  But don't forget to refresh the Frost Blade often.

Comment: I suppose Frost Blade is available to Reina as well? I have found no weapons so far.

Comment: I truly have no idea.  I've only played with one character so far, though I'm guessing since the ability is key (or greatly helps) for a boss fight, that all characters should have access to similar spells.

My other iterations before I found this function of Frost Blade was by using Refresh all the time, though even with 2 life potions, I've never been able to kill the boss that way.  You kinda have to attack him with long-reach attacks if you don't want his counters to hit you, and they aren't that readily available to the character I used.

Comment: @badp 'Frost Blade' is the *up* magic for ice, which temporarily enchants your weapon/attacks with the power of Ice.  I guess Reina gets different magic than Wyatt, which is unfortunate.  Reina is apparently much more difficult.

Comment: @elf Oh I do have that one as explained in the question. I only saw a minor boost in damage without realising it changed the boss pattern. I'll try again spamming the spell more consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's how to deal with the boss:

- You need to have Aegis as your side spell (when playing as Reina)
- You need to have Frost Blade as your up spell
- You want to have Ice Tower as your down spell
- You want to have the kick-out-of-guard skill, (when playing as Reina) if the fight against Magus already didn't make this abundantly clear.
- You want to remember that your cancel skill (moving down) allows you to regain movement after being hit. This is crucial to avoid getting damaged for hundreds of points in one go.
- You want to remember that you have a helper and it's worth from time to time to remember to use your left trigger for it for some free damage. The divine air spell also is nice for this purpose.
- If you run out of mana, you're kind of screwed. Watch your mana consumption. Making an ice tower to jump onto for safety sounds nice, but you may run out of juice too fast that way; I did. Using the horizontal fire cannons as ledges costs no mana, takes no more time and is harder to get wrong.

Here's a list of things the boss can do:

- Attack you in quick succession. If you can, parry. Otherwise, just guard is fine. You can even take the hits; he doesn't hit for much so long as he doesn't push you into a fire column.
- Guard. Kick him out of guard, stun him and get some damage in.
- Jump up fast. This causes a wave of fire to spread on the floor. If the fire columns aren't active, save some mana by jumping on top of them. Otherwise, you can spend some mana by using Ice Tower and jumping up there, but I found it's more reliable to just run away and jump back at him. Once you're there you can safely use Frost Blade to bump your damage and [avoid his bubble defense](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/149419/23).
- Jump up slowly. This is his huge fireball nuke plus fire laser attack, and unless you get hurt into it, it's a fairly easy combo to avoid. Run for a corner. When a fire lazer forms above you, let go of the controller and let the fireball nuke thing slowly suck you in, avoiding the laser; once that's done, run again towards the corner. You should be able to get 0 damage out of this fairly easily.